# how can I nest a formArray inside another formArray using reactive forms

Tags: angular

I have a reactive form that uses arrays and has this structure:

```
 this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  names: this.fb.array([
    this.fb.group({ element_name: [null, [Validators.required]] }),
    this.fb.group({ element_name: [null, [Validators.required]] }),
  ])
```

[image]

Everything works well, performs the respective validations.

I want to add the `lastname` in another text field and have the required validation, but I do not know what is the way to accommodate like in the image:

[image]

I tried to do something similar like what I did with `"names"` but it doesn't make a mistake. What I can do?

this is my live code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nm2vah?file=app/app.component.html

this is my code:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div formArrayName="names">
      <ng-container
          *ngFor="let item of myForm.get('names').controls; let i=index">
          <div [formGroupName]="i">
                  name <input type="text" class="form-control" id="element_name"
                      formControlName="element_name"
                      placeholder="insert name" 
                  >
                  <!--lastname 
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="element_lastname"
                      formControlName="element_lastname"
                      placeholder="insert last name" 
                  >-->
          </div>
      </ng-container>
  </div>
</form>


this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  names: this.fb.array([
    this.fb.group({ element_name: [null, [Validators.required]] }),
    this.fb.group({ element_name: [null, [Validators.required]] }),
  ]),
  lastname: this.fb.array([
    this.fb.group({ element_name: [null, [Validators.required]] }),
    this.fb.group({ element_name: [null, [Validators.required]] }),
  ])

})
```

Comment: I don't understand your exact need but to be cleaner with solution use form array and form group like here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-htegps ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add last name to same form group of the firt name.

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  names: this.fb.array([
    this.fb.group({
      element_name: [null, [Validators.required]],
      element_lastname: [null, [Validators.required]]
    }),
    this.fb.group({
      element_name: [null, [Validators.required]],
      element_lastname: [null, [Validators.required]]
    }),
  ]),
})
```

And Your Html:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div formArrayName="names">
      <ng-container
          *ngFor="let item of myForm.get('names').controls; let i=index">
          <div [formGroupName]="i">
                  name <input type="text" class="form-control" id="element_name"
                      formControlName="element_name"
                      placeholder="insert name" 
                  >

                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="element_lastname"
                      formControlName="element_lastname"
                      placeholder="insert last name" 
                  >
          </div>
      </ng-container>
  </div>
</form>
```